# “pulled Portugal level” mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> He was rendered mostly ineffective by Uruguay’s stout defense; it was fellow veteran Pepe – not No. 7 – whose powerful header **pulled Portugal level** 10 minutes into the second half after Cavani put the Uruguyans ahead in the first.

I figure **level** here is like an adverb and **pulled Portugal level** means pull Portugal back to the competition because of the score by that powerful header. But I don't know if I understand it correctly. What's the correct way of understanding **pulled Portugal level** in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two things are level, then they are at the same height (or distance, size and so on). If the scores are level, it means the two sides have scored the same

the phrase "to pull level" means to accelerate to reach the same point as someone. For example you might say that "a car pulled level with me when overtaking".

The goal caused the scores to become equal. You could also say it "levelled the scores"

Comment: I can't find a good dictionary definition for "pull level"   any suggestions?

Comment: I was trying to get it anywhere,but I didn't find it either.

Comment: I am curious if *pull level* is a set indeed. Maybe we should take 'pull' and 'level' separately?

Comment: "draw level" is in wiktionary, and that is a close synonym.

Comment: @dan - I don’t think it’s idiomatic; it rings like sportswriter journalism to my ear. It just means, “pulled Portugal into a tie.”

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean be "not idiomatic" but "sportswriter journalism". The fact that it has use by journalists is evidence for it being idiomatic.

Comment: @JamesK - I’ll try to elaborate. By definition, _idiomatic_ means _using, containing, or denoting expressions that are natural to a native speaker_. I can’t think of anyone who would say, “That header pulled Portugal level,” while watching or recapping a game. However, I’m not surprised to read something like that in a sports column. Sports journalists seem to have a knack for sprinkling compact but oddly-worded phrases into more common vernacular, such as: _Gerard Pique smashed Spain’s second in off the post, but 38-year-old Sergei Ignashevich **wrong-footed David De Gea to equalize**_.

Comment: @J.R. I don't quite understand the last sentence you quoted. Can you elaborate a bit? Thanks!

Comment: @Dan - That's my point. It's a sentence I extracted from a World Cup article. Sportswriters seem to write as if they are a little worried about overusing the word _tie_, so they will often use verbs like _knotted, equalize,_ or _pull level_ in its stead – substitutes we may not hear so often in casual conversation. The sentence makes more sense if you watched the shootout; it means: _Gerard Pique scored on Spain's second penalty kick, on a shot that deflected in off the post, but Ignashevich tricked the Spanish goalie into diving the wrong way to even the penalty kick score._